# Using functional programming to search user input against file

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

Full discolsure this is a homework assignment so I'm not asking for straight up answers, just would like help with breaking down the problem. We were just taught very roughly the use of functional programming, and I'd like to apply it to my current assignment.

My assignment is to compare words entered by the user to a list of valid words that is given in a file, where each line in the file is one valid word. 
My thinking was creating a stream from the file, then filtering each word from the file based on if its a word that was entered by the user(the user can enter multiple words).

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem exactly, and would love a way to help think about the problem or resources that would help.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Well...all of this depends on what language you're using. If I was using JS, I would either make sure the file stored the words as an array (or convert them into an array) and then use .contains() to check if the word is there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: He mentioned `Java` in the tags so i guess he can't use JS

Answer (score 0):

First you should load your valid words and store in your variable. (Prefer `Set<String>` to store because its `contains` check is fast.)

```
Set<String> validWords = File.lines(your file).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then you can check if use enter correct word by using `Set.contains()` method

```
validWords.contains(XXX);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following guiding steps:

1. Read the user input
2. Split it into words and store them in a `Set`
3. Read the file as a `Stream` with `Files.lines()`
4. Use `Stream.filter()` to select all words which occur in the `Set` (Hint: use `Set.contains()`)
5. Do something with those leftover values. E.g. count them / or collect them into a DataStructure and so on.

Alternativly if you want to just check that the user input is contained in the `Stream` you may use `Stream.anyMatch()`